# Putting operators like + and - in variables ? C++

Tags: c++

I was wondering how to make a stack that can handle operators .. like: 1+2*5 so the first stack will take the 1,2 and 5 ... and another stack take the operators + and * in C++

so I would be able to know which datatype I can use in the struct node :

```
struct node{
int data;
char operator [];
node* next;};
```

Comment: That is invalid. You cannot do that. Can you tell us what you want to do?

Comment: 1+2*5 the answer should be 11 2*5 = 10 and + 1 = 11 .... so the multiplication then the addition.i want to make it manually.but the 1,2 and 5 into a stack and the operators + and * ... then as the stack is LIFO.i will get from the first stack the 5 then * from the second one , then the 2 so the answer will be 10 (2*5) .. i will return the value into the first stack now the values in the first stack 1 then 10 and the second stack the + operator only.again calling from the first stack the 10 then the + then from the first stack the 1.and finally turns the addition 10 + 1 = 11 into the stack.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, don't create your own linked list implementation. C++ has standard stack (and list) types already. You probably want a stack of ints, and a stack of strings:

```
#include <stack>
#include <string>

std::stack <int> numbers;
std::stack <std::string> operators;
```

You could also use a stack of char for the operators:

```
std::stack <char> operators;
```

but using string allows for multi-character operators like `&&`.

Comment: Thanks Neil for the reply ... but actually that is an assignment and i have to do it like that

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass operators around as variables, which in my opinion is a slight failing. You could, however, use a generic function object (available in Boost) and produce functors for them, which would enable this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to customize the operators via operator overloading, u might as well do that..
All u need to do is create an enum of all the operators u wish to use and use the stack of that enum, this will solve following:
1. Checking of right operator entered or not.
2. Performing the operation without a stack of if/else or switch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood what you want to do, but every node can take one integer and a char containing the operator. This way, the first node contains for example 1, and '+', and the second should have 2 as data and '*' as operator, as for the last node, the operator should be null to mean that no more operations will be done.